Pyside6 qt designer QpushButton icon align
I'm having a problem with aligning the icon inside the button in rtl layout
the layout is set to RTL
i add this stylesheet
#side_bar QPushButton{
text-align: right;
}

without an icon the text-align in the right direction well
But after adding an icon:
the icon makes the extra space in the right direction instead of the left

This how it should look like


I'm not sure I understand. Where do you think the icon should go? Can you provide an image (even a mock up) of what you expect?

I EDITED the picture in post u can check it

Sorry but your new image doesn't clarify what issue you have. Please try to explain yourself better, and clarify the difference between what you get and what you want.

okay look at the last picture plz

Possibly related to QTBUG-64373, I see that you tagged PyQt5 and PySide6 so it's unclear to what Qt version you're referring to, but the fix has been added for Qt6 only (since 6.6.2 and 6.7), so check if you have at least one of those versions. There will be no fix for Qt5, so if you need for that the only solution would be to use a QPushButton subclass and attempt the drawing on your own using QStyle functions (and hoping that they don't break anything).

version pyside6 6.6.2

Did you then test it with Qt5? Did you get a different result at all? Note that when using RightToLeft you may also need to switch relative layout directions in some cases. Try by changing to text-align: left;. If it still doesn't work, but you see a difference in behavior with Qt5, it's possible that the change introduced in Qt6 didn't consider the QSS aspects, so I'd suggest you to do a few tests with all possible combinations (including setting the default QApplication layout direction) and eventually file a report on the Qt bug tracker.
